# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE Angular 2 + Node.js + Socket.io

Tags: node.js, angular, ssl, socket.io

I am developing a web app with Angular 2, Node.js and socket.io. It is working perfectly fine with http, however I wanted to implement https protocol and I hit the wall.

I am getting net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE on any http call from angular to my web api and also when trying to make a socket connection.

Here is what I did:

1) Generated my private key and csr.

2) Requested SSL certificate from Comodo using that csr.

3) Received 2 files from Comodo:
- domain.ca-bundle
- domain.crt

4) I copied those 2 files and my private key to a folder: /etc/apache2/ssl/

5) I modified default-ssl.conf in etc/apache2/sites-available to point to these files:

```
SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mypriv.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.ca-bundle
```

plus added:

```
ServerName domain.io
ServerAlias www.domain.io
```

6) Enabled https and restarted apache. Verified using SSL analyzer (https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/) if my cert is properly set up. It confirmed that connection to my site is now secure, so I assume this part was done properly and now I needed to fix the app and the server to handle https.

7) This is how socket connection is created in angular:

```
this.socket = io.connect('https://server_ip' + ':3000', {
```

rejectUnauthorized: false });

This is gonna give me net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE later on

8) Angular app is also making http requests to the server like this:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post('https://server_ip' + ':3000/register', 
JSON.stringify(userModel), options)
  .map(res => res.json())
```

This is gonna give me net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE as well (in response to OPTIONS call)

9) Now on the server side, this is the relevant piece of code:

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    ca: splitca('/etc/apache2/ssl/domain.ca-bundle'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/mypriv.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/domain.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
let io = require('socket.io')(https);

server.listen(3000, () => {
    logger.debug('server started on port');
})
```

Server starts up fine, but any call from angular results in net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE response (tried chrome, mozilla and IE). Both server and angular app are running on the same IP.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: The certificate is bound to a host name but you use an IP? (`server_ip`)

Comment: @dawka Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Yes, I made a dumb mistake as explained in @AlexK. comment